# Borrar Archivos de carpeta servidor

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

estoy tratando de borrar archivos pdf previamente subidos de una carpeta de mi servidor, he seguido varios tutoriales pero no me funciona y no encuentro el error, este es mi código: 
Aquí meto todos los archivos de la carpeta en un array

```
 $path = "documentos/polizas/";
        $directorio = dir($path);
        while ($archivo = $directorio->read()) {
            if ($archivo != " . " AND $archivo != "..")
            if (strtolower(substr($archivo, -3) == "pdf")) {
                $polizas[]=array(
                    "doc"=>$doc="<a href='documentos/polizas/$archivo' rel='nofollow' >$archivo</a>"
                );
            }
        }
    $directorio->close();
    include ("polizas.html");
```

Aquí los listo en el html

```
   <a id="tabladocumentos">
        <label class="col-lg-4">Documentos:</label>
             <?php
                foreach($polizas as $poliza){
                    echo $poliza['doc'];
                    echo "<a id='borrar'style='float:right;'><img src='img/borrar.png'></a>";
                    echo "<br>";
                 }
             ?>
     </table>
```

Este es el script que uso para borrarlo

```html
<script>
    $(document).on('ready', function() {
        $('#borrar').on('click', function(e) {
            var file=$(this).prev().attr("href");
            console.log(file)
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'ajax/borrados/polizas.php',
                type: 'post',
                data:{ file:file },
            })
                .done(function() {
                    alert("Eliminado correctamente!");
                })
                .fail(function() {
                    alert("Ha ocurrido un error");
                })
                .always(function() {

                });

        })
    })
</script>
```

y por ultimo el ajax que "lo borra" aunque no lo hace

```
<?php
unlink($_POST['file']);
?>
```

Comment: Estás repitiendo `id#borrar`... eso es un error. Trata de pasar `id="borrar"` a `class="borrar"` y también en **jQuery** donde `#borrar` debería ser `.borrar`

Comment: ahh no me di cuenta gracias, pero sigue sin ir tiene que ser un error de otro tipo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya lo he solucionado, el error era que me llegaba la url completa y solo necesitaba el nombre del archivo ya que el ajax se ejecutaba desde otro lugar

```
$(document).on('ready', function() {
    $('.borrar').on('click', function(e) {


   var file=$(this).prev().html();

    console.log(file)
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax/borrados/polizas.php',
        type: 'post',
        data:{ file:file },
    })
        .done(function() {
            alert("Eliminado correctamente!");
        })
        .fail(function() {
            alert("Ha ocurrido un error");
        })
        .always(function() {

            });

    })
})

unlink("../../documentos/polizas/".$_POST['file']);
```